# Symfony 3.4 and MySQl 8. General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away when running a transaction in a rabbitmq queue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, rabbitmq

I have one system (Symfony 5, symfony/messenger) sending data to another (Symfony 3.4, enqueue/enqueue-bundle 0.9) using a rabbitmq queue.
The data is used to create entities (stored in a MySql 8 database) that are executed within a transaction in case of a failure, to return the Database to the initial state.

My code is something like this (on the Symfony 3.4 side where the error is):

```
function runInsideTx(callable $fn)
    {
        $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

        try {
            $resp = $fn();

            $this->em->flush();
            $this->em->getConnection()->commit();

            return $resp;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $this->em->getConnection()->rollBack();

            throw $ex;
        }
    }
```

And inside runInsideTx I have code like

```
$this->functions->runInsideTx(function () use ($message) {
    $entity = new SomeEntity();
    ...
    $this->em->persist($entity);
    $this->em->flush();
})
```

Workers run inside a Docker container using supervisor:

```
[program:interop-manager_tasks-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /app/bin/console enqueue:transport:consume manager_tasks_processor manager_tasks_prod --message-limit=1 -vvv
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs=3600
stdout_logfile = /var/log/manager_tasks_worker_out.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/manager_tasks_worker_err.log
user=application
environment=HOME="/home/application",USER="application"
```

Randomly the error `General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away` occurs. Initially I had a MySql 5 Database and changed it to a MySql 8, which I am running inside a docker container with a single database.

**Update**
I have this error too:
Warning: `Error while sending QUERY packet.`
This happens sometimes. It could be that it sends the task to the queue three times and it fails the first two and the third it processes it without problems

I also added the following parameters when running the MySQl server:

```
command: --sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --max-allowed-packet=1G --innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M --innodb_lock_wait_timeout=500
```

But the problem persists.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  '%timeout%'`

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                     | Value    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                   | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout            | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout            | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout       | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout          | 500      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout        | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout               | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout                 | 31536000 |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout            | 30       |
| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout | 60       |
| mysqlx_interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| mysqlx_port_open_timeout          | 0        |
| mysqlx_read_timeout               | 30       |
| mysqlx_wait_timeout               | 28800    |
| mysqlx_write_timeout              | 60       |
| net_read_timeout                  | 30       |
| net_write_timeout                 | 60       |
| replica_net_timeout               | 60       |
| rpl_stop_replica_timeout          | 31536000 |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout            | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout                 | 60       |
| wait_timeout                      | 28800    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
```